# Impresiones directas en impresoras térmicas ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un sistema web en el que se pueden emitir comprobantes electrónicos, cuenta con un botón para crear el comprobante, una vez creado genera una nueva ventana con el pdf del comprobante y la opción de impresión del mismo, equivalente a presionar control + P.

Lo que yo quiero es hacer todo este proceso para un caso en el que se cuente con impresora termica, si hay alguna forma de que todo este proceso se resuma en un click al crear el comprobante y se imprima inmediatamente en la impresora térmica todos los datos(obviamente no se vera en el formato pdf).

He visto que hay algunas librerías en php que hacen lo que yo pido, pero no he podido encontrar en ASP.

Espero que me puedan ayudar o dar alguna idea de como poderlo lograr.

Answer (score 1):

Hola si mal no entendí lo que quieres es eliminar la ventana de dialogo, te dire que eso es practicamente imposible, bueno casi.. solo se puede en Firefox.
Primero deber ingresar about:config en la barra de navegacion, despues te saldra un anuncio y tu das click en "aceptar el riesgo".
Y te aparecera una ventana como la siguiente:
Entonces buscaras print.always_print_silent, como a mi, y te aseguras que este como "true"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que no te aparezca puedes agregarlo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribes print.always_print_silent tal cual y lo pones true.
Espero que te sirva, fue lo que me salvo a mi. Saludos.